# Change wikitext from Wiktionary to readable text

Tags: mediawiki-api, wiktionary, wikitext

How to exchange Wikitext (as seen in Witkionary sourcecode) into readable text (as seen in Wiktionary website).

So this source:

```
{{ru-verb|ходи́ть|impf|pf=сходи́ть}}
```

Should be seen as:

```
ходи́ть • (xodítʹ) impf (perfective сходи́ть)
```

It is called Template in Wikitext, but how to change that template into human readable text I cannot find in the documentation.

Anyone had similar problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Use [the parse API to get an HTML output](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7Bru-verb|%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7Cimpf|pf=%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7D%7D&prop=text&title=page_title&formatversion=2&format=json).

You can render the HTML by passing it to your browser...

I don't think MediaWiki can directly generate plain text output, but If that's what desired, one may use a third party library. 
In Python and using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and its [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method the code looks like this:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            'https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7Bru-verb|%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7Cimpf|pf=%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7D%7D&prop=text&title=page_title&formatversion=2&format=json'
        ).json()['parse']['text']
    ).get_text(strip=True)
'ходи́ть•(xodítʹ)impf(perfectiveсходи́ть)'
```

---

**Update:**

Use [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) functions in PHP:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $json = file_get_contents('https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7Bru-verb|%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7Cimpf|pf=%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C%7D%7D&prop=text&title=page_title&formatversion=2&format=json');
php > $json = json_decode($json, TRUE);
php > $html = $json['parse']['text'];
php > $pain_text = strip_tags(html_entity_decode ($html));
php > echo $pain_text;
ходи́ть • (xodítʹ) impf (perfective сходи́ть)
```

Comment: thx, I do not know how to use it in PHP :). I'll try to find out or wait for different answer, but thank you very much it will probbaly help me. Thank you!